# How to RDP machine "C" from machine "A" when machine "B" is in the middle

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, remote-desktop

Ok, I'm working on a rather complex network arrangement so I'll try my best to be clear. There are 3 PCs: A, B and C.

A: Ubuntu 12.04, the one on my desk: it's part of an intranet 125.1.x.x/16

B: Windows XP, a remote PC which has 2 NICs, NIC#1: 125.1.x.x/16, NIC#2: 192.168.7.x/24

C: Windows server 2008, a remote PC in the network 192.168.7.x/24

A "sees" B but not C;
B "sees" both A and C;
C "sees" B but not A;

Now to the challenge: I need to RDP (remote desktop) C from A.

What I do right now is RDP B, and from inside B, RDP C. So I have a remote connection within a remote connection. The problem is that I need to work on both B and C simultaneously, so I rather have both RDP windows separately, and not C confined within the boundaries of the B screen.

I hope I've been clear.

What I tried so far:
-In A: add a static route to network 192.168.7.0/24 with gateway 125.1.b.b
-In B: turn to "1" the "IPEnableRouter" registry entry (HKLM/System/"CCS"/Services/TCPIP/Parameters/)

No success.

Comment: I think you are probably on the right tracks with your routes, are you able to ping C from A? Can your run route print and add to your question?

Comment: Thanks Charles, I already solved the problem using Eugen's solution. For the record only: I wasn't able to ping C from A, the route was rightfully added, I verified that. The problem was probably in B (XP) which wasnt forwarding packets coming from NIC#1 to NIC#2 for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a port forwarder on B, that forwards e.g. Port 125.1.x.y:3390 on B to 192.168.7.y:3389 on C.

From A now if you connect

- to B on standard port 3389, you will get Desktop B
- to B on port 3390, you will get Desktop C

**EDIT**

Why? Because you want to

- neither mess around with the routing, creating potentially unwanted side effects or even security risks
- nor use XP as a router (while as a port proxy might be fine)

Comment: That sounds good! Thanks. Can you recommend some freeware port forwarding? Be aware I ve no access to any router, so the forwarding you suggest MUST rely entirely on software within machine B.

Comment: Take a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/pjs-passport/

Comment: Eugen, you're THE MAN! It worked just as expected. Many thanks!